# How to debug multiple C files in vscode?

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code

i need to debug two differents files "scanner.c" and "memory.c" in vscode. When I click the "build and debug" it shows me an error, i click "debug anyway" and it opens "launch.json" with the following text inside:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": ["scanner.c", "memory.c"],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
    }
    
]
```

}

Comment: What is the "an error" that is shown? Maybe it's trying to tell you something useful.

Comment: @dratenik it says "The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: gcc build active file' terminated with exit code 1." And the options are "Abort" and "Debug Anyway"

Comment: Can you run the pre launch task `C/C++: gcc build active file` manually and see what errors you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug multiple C/C++ files simultaneously in VsCode you need to build a debuggable executable out of them first (using a build system like `make`) then start debugging the executable itself.
A quick google search brings up a good reference to follow:

> https://dev.to/talhabalaj/setup-visual-studio-code-for-multi-file-c-projects-1jpi

Comment: Is not it the task of ODE remove this pain? Are you familiar with another development environment that saves this pain from me?