# ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". VSCode with Ubuntu-22.04 using WSL

Tags: c, json, gdb, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

So I was trying to debug my C code using VSCode in WSL (Ubuntu 22.04) and after using different methods, I always get the same [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZysK.png).

Firstly I tried following this [guide](https://dev.to/talhabalaj/setup-visual-studio-code-for-multi-file-c-projects-1jpi) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654716/how-to-debug-multiple-c-files-in-vscode),
Idk if I did something wrong, heres the "launch.json":

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "build"
    },
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my "tasks.json":

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
      {
          "label": "build",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "make",
          "group": {
              "kind": "build",
              "isDefault": true
          },
          "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
      }
  ]
}
```

Secondly I tried following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVyYnOHP4nY) which doesn't use the make file I used in the guide.
here's the "launch.json"

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
    },
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
    }
    ]
}
```

and "tasks.json"

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I also tried executing vscode in admin mode and using `chmod -x [my main file]` in the terminal, where `[my main file]` is the location of the binary output from the build.

And finally I used the vscode extension [C/C++ runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=franneck94.c-cpp-runner) to see if I was missing something.

In ALL this cases the debug console showed the same issue.

```
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x8001245
Cannot insert breakpoint 2.
Cannot access memory at address 0x8001260
```

And the terminal shows this warning:

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-ri4karkl.dco" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-3varx35x.tnm"
```